# Unzip password protected archive and read the containing SPSS file into R

Tags: r, spss, hmisc

I have a password protected zip archive containing one SPSS system data file (*.sav). And I want to unpack it and read its content into R. From what I googled, `Hmisc::getZip` seems to be the best bet. And I've tried some different approaches.

First try was to just run the function, hoping that it would spit out the `*.sav` file in my `getwd()` location.

```
getZip(url = '/path/to/data.zip', 
  password = 'foo'
)
```

But this command returns:

```
"unzip -p -P foo data.zip" 
class 
"pipe" 
mode 
"r" 
text 
"text" 
opened 
"closed" 
can read 
"yes" 
can write 
"yes"
```

And after reading the help file, the `getZip()` function seems to return a file O/I pipe. So my second try was to use `getZip()` inside `read.spss()`. Like this:

```
data <- read.spss(getZip(url = '/path/to/data.zip', 
  password = 'foo')
)
```

But no love:

```
Error in read.spss(getZip(url = '/path/to/data.zip', password = 'foo')) : 
  unable to open file: 'No such file or directory'
```

When I take the command from my first try "`unzip -p -P foo data.zip`" and run it (with an added "`> data.sav`") from the command line I get the SPSS file. So something is working. My third try was to use the connection:

```
file_connection <- getZip(url = '/path/to/data.zip', password = 'foo')
open(file_connection, 'rb')
data <- readBin(file_connection, raw())
close(file_connection)
```

I was hoping to save the data object to an `*.sav` file and read it back into R with the `read.spss()` function. But the data object is not an SPSS file:

```
> data
[1] 24
```

So... How should I successfully unpack and read the `*.sav` file from the password protected zip archive into R?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8          LC_NUMERIC=C                 
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8           LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8       
 [5] LC_MONETARY=sv_SE.UTF-8       LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8      
 [7] LC_PAPER=sv_SE.UTF-8          LC_NAME=sv_SE.UTF-8          
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=sv_SE.UTF-8        LC_TELEPHONE=sv_SE.UTF-8     
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=sv_SE.UTF-8    LC_IDENTIFICATION=sv_SE.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] gmailr_0.7.1 rj_2.0.5-1  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.5         Formula_1.2-1       cluster_2.0.4      
 [4] magrittr_1.5        splines_3.3.0       munsell_0.4.3      
 [7] rj.gd_2.0.0-1       colorspace_1.2-6    lattice_0.20-33    
[10] R6_2.1.2            httr_1.1.0          plyr_1.8.3         
[13] tools_3.3.0         nnet_7.3-12         grid_3.3.0         
[16] data.table_1.9.6    gtable_0.2.0        latticeExtra_0.6-28
[19] openssl_0.9.3       survival_2.39-4     Matrix_1.2-6       
[22] gridExtra_2.2.1     RColorBrewer_1.1-2  ggplot2_2.1.0      
[25] base64enc_0.1-3     acepack_1.3-3.3     rpart_4.1-10       
[28] curl_0.9.7          scales_0.4.0        Hmisc_3.17-4       
[31] jsonlite_0.9.20     chron_2.3-47        foreign_0.8-66
```

**EDIT:** OK. So I have a (not so elegant) workaround. I'm using a `system()` call with the `wait = TRUE` argument to unpack the file. Like this:

```
system(command = paste0('unzip -P foo ', data.zip), 
  wait = TRUE
)
```

Then I can read the `*.sav` file into R. But I still don't understand how to use `Hmisc::getZip()`